# RegEx to return only matching group using only replace method

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Is there a way to return only the matching group using only replace?

I have this string,

> "xml version 2.1.2-emerald https://www.example.com"

and I want to pull the version out of it.

I'm using this RegEx:

```
const regex = /\sversion\s(.*?)\s/;
const str = `xml version 2.1.2-emerald https://www.example.com`;
const subst = `$1`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result); 
// desired result: "2.1.2-emerald"
```

Except I want the result to contain only the match. Is there a way to do this with the `replace()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the key is to fully collect the entire string data, then replace it with the desired group:

```js
const regex = /.*\sversion\s(.*?)\s.*/gs;
const str = `xml version 2.1.2-emerald https://www.example.com`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `replace`, `match` instead, and extract the first captured group. You can also use `(\S+)` instead of `(.*?)\s`:

```js
const regex = /\sversion\s(\S+)/;
const str = `xml version 2.1.2-emerald https://www.example.com`;
const result = str.match(regex);
console.log(result[1]);
```

If there may not be a match, check that the result isn't `null` first:

```js
const regex = /\sversion\s(.*?)\s/;
const str = `foo bar`;
const result = str.match(regex);
if (result) {
  console.log(result[1]);
}
```

If you want the full match to be just what you're looking for, you can use lookbehind, though this will only work on newer browsers, and is not a good cross-browser solution:

```js
const regex = /(?<=\sversion\s)\S+/;
const str = `xml version 2.1.2-emerald https://www.example.com`;
const result = str.match(regex);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: That's the full match. (from the `version` to the `\s` at the very end of the pattern)